# Configure JWT Access Token in .NET core 2 MVC application

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I was successful in retrieving an Authorization token from Azure Active Directory in a console application. I want to convert this code to .Net Core MVC but not sure how to configure everything cleanly in Startup.cs

I assume the key/value pairs would be moved to appsettings.json, but how do I get this token under `ConfigureServices()`?

```
    var client = new HttpClient();

    var uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantid>/oauth2/token";

    var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", "{resourceID}"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "{clientID}"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "{clientSecret}"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "openid")
     };

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
    var response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;

    string result = string.Empty;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(result);
        string token = (string)jObject.SelectToken("access_token");
    }
```

Should I use one of the below methods to obtain the bearer token? I'm doing a POST in the console application, but that doesn't seem right for Startup configuration.

```
services.AddAuthentication()
```

or

```
.AddJwtBearer()
```

Comment: Are you writing a Web App? or a Web API?
If you are writing a Web App, I advise you to have a look at the following sample: [active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2). It has 2 parts:
- sign-in a user to the Web App
- get a token for the signed-in user to call an API: in the branch named [signInAndCallMsGraph
](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/signInAndCallMsGraph)

Comment: also, I would not recommend you to get an access token like you do, especially you are using the client credentials grant, which means there is a secret (unless this console app runs on a server with very controlled access). Auth libraries will help you doing that for all kind of [scenarios](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/scenarios), see for instance MSAL.NET. it seems that what you want to do is [Acquiring a token for the app](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows)

Comment: Ok, thanks for that sample, I got it to run and authenticate, but it doesn't provide an authentication token. I'm trying to call an existing API I developed as an App service in Azure

Comment: I'm going through Jean-Marc's other sample flow, I'll get back to you @JoeyCai

Answer (score 1):

> I got it to run and authenticate, but it doesn't provide an authentication token.

As Jean said, you could use Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) which is the library that helps you to develop applications that work with v2.0 endpoint and here you could use it to get access token.

The scope here is the resource you want affixed with `.default`. Refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token).

> The value passed for the scope parameter in this request should be the resource identifier (Application ID URI) of the resource you want, affixed with the `.default` suffix. For the Microsoft Graph example, the value is `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`. This value informs the v2.0 endpoint that of all the direct application permissions you have configured for your app, it should issue a token for the ones associated with the resource you want to use.

The following is the C# MSAL sample code, which gets the access token for this application permission’s scenario.You need to install the NuGet package [Microsoft.Identity.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/)  in your project.

```
ConfidentialClientApplication app = new ConfidentialClientApplication("clientId",
    "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/v2.0",
    "redirectUrl",
    new ClientCredential("clientSecret"),
    new TokenCache(),null);
AuthenticationResult authResult = app.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(
    new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"}).Result;
var token = authResult.AccessToken;
```

Here you could change `Microsoft Graph API` to your API `Application ID URI` and for more details about adding permission and so on, you could refer to this [article](https://tsmatz.wordpress.com/2016/10/07/application-permission-with-v2-endpoint-and-microsoft-graph/).

Comment: The sample code works, I get a token and response from the graph API. But when I change the graph URL to my newly created scope (api://xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx/testscope), I get the error "The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope ./default works but it returns 401 when I try calling my API endpoints

Comment: Based on this artice, v2 endpoints cannot be used in calling APIs on another directory like my scenario. https://zure.com/blog/azure-ad-v2-and-msal-from-developers-point-of-view/

Comment: Have you add permission to your API? Or would you mind changing the flow like this [one](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an OWIN startup class instead. Refer this sample from Microsoft

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-aspnet-webapp

Comment: I'm using a daemon application so I can't have a login screen